# Is there any guideline on the plural form of loanwords from Japanese?

Tags: loanwords, grammatical-number

I just saw a trailer of *47 Ronin*. My first thought was "that doesn't sound right". We have *12 Monkeys* and *13 Warriors*. Why *47 **Ronin***? Then I recalled that there is a movie titled *Seven Samurai*.

I checked the words **ronin** and **samurai** with Google, and found that the plural form of *ronin* can be either *ronin* or *ronins*. But the plural form of *samurai* is *samurai*.

Is there any guideline on the plural form(s) of loanwords in English, especially those from Japanese?

Comment: This is a duplicate question.

Comment: Which one, I searched but couldn't find one?

Comment: That question doesn't say anything at all about guidelines, rules, or patterns. From the accepted answer: *"So yes, ninja meaning ninjas is a usage that gets some use, but regular pluralized ninjas is more common, and perfectly grammatical."* Can I conclude that there is no such guideline, and I should always consult dictionaries? What if I'd like to write some word borrowed from Japanese and it wasn't in any dictionary?

Comment: I believe there is no such guideline; consult dictionaries. (Actually, one guideline is to only take irregular inflected plurals from a few selected languages—probably German, French, Greek, Latin, Hebrew. You certainly shouldn't use things like Hungarian plurals: [*one coach; two coachik*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kocsi#Hungarian)). For loan-words from Japanese, though, I don't think there's any reason not to use the zero plural.

Comment: Two nindzi :)...